# Adding Multiple row values to multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, shopping-cart

So I have this CART table which stores the selected items of the customer and ORDER table which stores the ordered items of the customer, obviously, I would like to transfer/add the selected item of the customer to the ORDER table. I want to do it like `INSERT INTO` (array of product_names,size,price,etc..) into the ORDER table because customers can have multiple items in the cart. I really need your help :|

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from cart where user_id =$session_id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $cartItems = array('user_id'=$row[user_id],'product_name'=>$row['product_name'],     'price'=>$row['price'], 'size'=>$row['size']);
}
```

Comment: Don't be *tamad* enough to specify the schema of the tables `:)`

Comment: @JW, Logic lng po need ko :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could another database for that, say `ORDER DB` and `ORDERED _ITEMS table` then when you insert items in the `ORDERED_ITEMS table` you can use `mysql_insert_id()` and insert the `user_id` into the `ORDERD DB` and from there you can join the two tables